# Replace table with csv file - SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssms

Is there a way to replace the contents of a table with the contents of a `.csv` file in SQL Server Management Studio?

The reason for this is I made a mistake on a SQL query which overwrote all of the data in one column (thank god I did it on a test server).

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Look at the `linked server` or `OPENROWSET` or `OPENQUERY`.

Comment: Also you can use the task/import data option in SQL Management Studio, and import directly from csv.

Answer (score 1):

Drop/truncate the table, then import the data via bulk insert TSQL statement, import/export wizard, or bcp.exe from command line.  If you dropped the table, then ensure to recreate your indexes after that.